# What to do with my collection of old third-party Pentax zooms with Canon camera?

Tags: lens, canon, pentax

I just dug 4 lenses out of the closet with my old film Pentax. I have the following:

- Quantaray 35-80mm f4-5.6
- Quantaray 70-210mm f4-5.5
- Albinar Macro Zoom 80-200mm f3.9
- Promaster AF 100-400mm f4.5-6.7

While busy working, I just switched to the Canon EF-S 18-55mm that came with my Canon Rebel EOS Rebel T6. I'm retired now and want to get back into photography, but on a very limited budget. What's your advice?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your question? Is it whether you can use these old lenses on your Canon camera? Or whether you should get a different camera to utilize them better? Or something else?

Comment: Why so many telephoto zooms?  There are cheap adapter rings for PK-EF, but I'd worry about the aperture-control pin interfering with the mirror.

Comment: At a guess for why this selection — the first two are a set, the third is an upgrade for the second, and the fourth was added for more reach.

Comment: on the risk of going slightly off topic, as a fellow owner of a T6 on a tight budget, consider the EF-S 24mm 2.8STM and the EF-S 55-250 mm STM. Both are cheap (for lenses), complement each other nicely and you get a bit of reach (250mm) and a bit of low light capabilities (with the 24mm). I almost stopped using the 18-55 from the kit after getting those, because it is noisy/slow to focus and not nearly as sharp as the other two.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea I would receive so many responses so quickly.  Thank you. Although my question DID need clarification, you were able to intuit what I needed (should I buy a new camera to fit these lenses, buy an adaptor so I can use them with my Canon Rebel, or buy new lenses developed for my Canon). I’ve made a note on my phone of the new lenses you suggested adding as funds allow.  I’ll go that way.  This is an amazing community and blessings on each of your heads for your kindness.

Answer (score 3):

These lenses are all budget zooms from third party labelers. (That is, they didn't make them; they sourced them from a low-cost lens manufacturer and put their brand on them.) They may have some charm and be fun, but they're not very high quality by the standards of their day, let alone today's much, much higher standards.

So, while your question is very broad, I can simplify one thing. Don't worry about trying to make these lenses work. It's just not worth it.

Comment: These also (maybe with the exception of the 100-400) won't fetch much, so best to just store them in case you happen on a DSLM or a Pentax DSLR, you'll have a starter set of telephotos ....